# ASP.NET Session Shopping Cart Items issue on pageload not updating

Tags: asp.net

I.e. I have a piece of code on my page as follows, which is in page_load

```
Dim subTotal As Integer = 0
    For Each item As CartItem In ShoppingCart.Instance.Items
        subTotal += 1
    Next

    strShoppingCart.Append(subTotal).Append(" Items")
    shoppingCartItems.Text = strShoppingCart.ToString()
```

And I can then add items to my cart as follows

Protected Sub Update_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim rowscount As Integer = productListTable.Rows.Count

```
    For Each row As GridViewRow In productListTable.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            ' We'll use a try catch block in case something other than a number is typed in. If so, we'll just ignore it.
            Try
                ' Get the productId from the GridView's datakeys
                Dim productId = Convert.ToInt32(productListTable.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
                ' Find the quantity TextBox and retrieve the value
                Dim quantity = Integer.Parse(CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("txtQuantity"), TextBox).Text)
                'Dim price = Decimal.Parse(CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("TradePriceField"), Label).Text)
                Dim price = Decimal.Parse("16.00")
                Dim productName = CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("ProductNameField"), Label).Text
                Dim packSize = Integer.Parse(CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("PackSizeField"), Label).Text)
                Dim stockIndicator = Integer.Parse(CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("PackSizeField"), Label).Text)
                ShoppingCart.Instance.AddItem(productId, quantity, price, productName, packSize, stockIndicator)


            Catch ex As FormatException

            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is as follows

Page Load
Items Count is 0

I add a product the page still says 0 Items when there is actually 1 item in session
I refresh the page the counter goes to one

How can I to read from correct session count ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page_Load` is going to fire before `Update_Click`, which is why you're not seeing the count increase after the initial form submit. You'll need to either update the `shoppingCartItems` control after `Update_Click` executes, or you can `Response.Redirect` back to the page to get the display to update. I personally like to use `Response.Redirect` after a post because if the user refreshes the page then you won't see that browser message that says it is going to repost the data.

You also might want to check out the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: hey rsbarro question response.redirecting for every click seems very resource heavy or am I wrong ? Also how can I update ShoppingCartItems after update_click I thought I was updating it in Update_Click method i.e. ShoppingCart.Instance.AddItem(productId, quantity, price, productName, packSize, stockIndicator)

Comment: ah placing my code which display the session count in Page_PreRender seems to have done the trick

Comment: @StevieB: I don't think the redirect approach is resource heavy. I view it as a necessity to make the user experience better, since that repost dialog is confusing (and can be displayed in several situations, like a page refresh, or a back button then forward button click). A standard approach in ASP.NET is to bind data in the Page_Load, taking into account if it is a postback (i.e. if(!Page.IsPostBack) DataBindMyControls();)`. Any postback events (like a button click) can then update whatever they need to update, and then you can just Response.Redirect to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a shopping cart, but I used AJAX updatepanels and the Redirect did not work the AJAX way.

I used `mycartlistview.DataBind()` in my code after an item was added to the shopping cart.